# How to active a div tag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, jquery-ui, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo UI grid and Form and these are separated by a Kendo splitter.

```
<div id="splitter" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
        <div id ="grid" style="height:100%;width:100%;"></div>
        <div id ="Form" style="display:none">
             <input type = "text"/>
             <input type ="button"/>
        </div>
 </div>
```

Initially I have to display grid in the left half of the splitter, after selecting a row in the grid I want to display the form in the right side of the splitter (I want to active the "Form" div tag). How can I do this?

Comment: what do you meen active? If i understood correctly you need $('#splitter').focus();

Comment: display content in the "Form" tag,after selecting the row only

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're after, but it seems you'd like to display the hidden Form.

```
$("#Form").show();
```

This line should of course be part of the grid row selection handler that either happens by selecting some checkbox (usually firct grid column when implemented this way) or by clicking a grid row. In any case, you should add upper line to your event handler.

But until you provide some details how you select rows in your grid, we can't be more detailed because everything is just speculation and may have no relevant connection to reality.

> ***FYI**: It seems that your question doesn't have anything to do with your splitter and seems to be more a distraction.*

Answer (score 0):

Try also this code on click event

```
 $("#Form").css("display","block");
```